# sqlite3 database load to memory c++ and select perfomance

Tags: c++, sqlite

Is there any method to load sqlite3 database file from disk into memory before make any `SELECTS` on it? `sqlite3_step()` work really slow... So I want to load database into the memory to load the data quickly.

Before sqlite3 I use simple binary data serialization and all members of stackoverflow suggested to me to use `sqlite3` for serialization and now my program is really slow.. so slow that I can not unserialize all my data. (Serialization work well with transactions)

Maybe also this will help. my `SELECT`:
there are two selects and two `sqlite3_step()` on each unserialized object.
queries looks like `SELECT aaaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,ggg,hhh,fff,jjj FROM table` for two queries. 
First table with unique `aaaa` key, but second one not unique (so seems its without indexes at all)

**UPDATE:**

```
    // Create SQL statement
    std::string sql_createtable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ssssssss(" \
        "sid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
        "last_access_time       INT     ," \
        "last_c_time        INT     ," \
        "total_c           INT     ," \
        "last_viewed_lid INT ," \
        "last_viewed_ltid INT     );";  
//      "showed TEXT     );";

    std::string sql_showed = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS showed(" \
        "sid              INT     NOT NULL," \
        "rid              INT     ," \
        "lid         INT     ," \
        "ltid           INT         );";
```

**Select 1:**

```
SELECT sid, last_access_time, last_c_time, total_c, last_viewed_lid, last_viewed_ltid FROM ssssss
```

**Select 2:**

```
"SELECT rid, lid, ltid FROM showed WHERE sid= ?1"; // sid is from first table. can be more than 1 the same sid
```

Hmm, seems the problem that `sid` at the second table `showed` is not unique and no index? How to add index to this statement ?

Maybe some other suggestions?

Comment: Loading the data to memory is responsibility of the operating system. It will do pretty good job of it. It's more likely that your selects are simply very unoptimal. But for that you'll have to show us the _exact_ selects and schema (rename columns as you want if you need to anonymize, but all clauses and conditions must match).

Answer (score 1):

You want to add index. Since the column is not unique, you need to add it with separate command:

```
CREATE INDEX showed_sid ON showed (sid);
```

Just execute this right after creating the table.

Comment: thanks, is it oplimal index for my purposes? i found http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html this (paragraph 5.0 The Skip-Scan Optimization) seems need to add all colums to index or not?

Comment: @abrahab: If all the columns you are reading are index too, sqlite reads the result directly from the index and does not need to access the main table. But it enlarges the index and that slows it down. So if you have a query that just reads a few columns from a table with many more, definitely go for it and add the result columns to the index as well. But if you are reading all columns it may be a little faster or it may be slower. In either case the difference will be small compared to what you gain by having index at all. If it's really performance critical, you should test it.

Comment: thank you, now i can confirm that with your solution my selection works much faster, but now new problem :( database is large and I get `bad_alloc` while unserialization in progress on big tables :( bad, because when I use binary data file to serialize/unserialize - i haven't had such problems. maybe a memory leak somewhere, but seems I do `_reset` on each `_step`...

Comment: @abrahab: sqlite is pure C and won't give a C++ exception. Also you really need to waste a _lot_ of memory to get `bad_alloc` by actually exhausting it. The most likely reason for `bad_alloc` is passing invalid size to `new[]`. As for the `_reset`, it is only for stopping queries that would return more rows before reusing them and I don't think I've ever used it. It might even be source of your problem, because it discards the row, so if you call it before doing the deserialization, the deserialization is getting invalid pointers for string and blob columns and random numbers for numeric ones.

Comment: it's crash on `std::sting` creating ( used new[] ). Also seems I have performance problem with `_reset` because I call it in each step (before you post you answer I think that it's necessary to do on each step when I bind the new values to prepared statement. thank you.